# MySQL fulltext search on multiple tables - another one

Tags: mysql

So I checked around about MySQL fulltext search on multiple, made-to-be joint tables. I know, now, that this is not possible because an index cannot be made on joint tables. The given solution is always to do two "match" with and/or – but it doesn't solve my problem.

The situation is as follows. I got :
– A "works" table that contains book titles, short descriptions and texts extracts.
– A "authors" table, with the name of the authors.

My search must be made IN BOOLEAN MODE for some reasons. Also, the default behavior for the words entered in the search field is AND (I preprocess the request by replacing spaces with +).

A user will typically enter in the search field : "NameOfAuthor TitleOfTheBook" or "NameOfAuthor aRandomWord (that he looks for in the extracts)" or "TitleOfTheBook" alone. He expect to find out only the results (and all of them) that matches all the word he entered.

So if I :
– match against the "works" fields OR the "authors" fields, I will have an answer only if the short descriptions in the "works" table mention the name of the author.
If I don't preprocess the query (if I don't transform "NameOfAuthor TitleOfTheBook" into "+NameOfAuthor +TitleOfTheBook"), I will have all the books from one author and all the books that contains some words of the query, which is not suitable.

– match against the "works" fields AND the "authors" fields, I will have nothing. If I don't preprocess the query for the "Match against author" part, it may work in this case, but not in general, because it will not work with any search that doesn't mention the author's name.

It seems to me that the only solution is an index that would mix works fields and  author name. But it's not possible to do an index over a joint… The situation seems so typical that I can't believe that this is a real issue. So I'm probably stupid, but I just can't figure a solution. Any idea ? Must I create a specific, virtual table for this search ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Well, writing down the question helped me to figure something… The idea would be to crush the user input into an $wordsArray and do the fulltext search for each of them.

So, the idea would be to :

```
//Parse the words from the query field  
    for (there is still a $word to check in the $wordsArray) {  
       // do a fulltext search on "works" fields against $word OR "authors" fields against $word
       // save the results in a multi-dimensional $resultArray
    }

// Keep only the results that exists in every row of the $resultArray
// Display
```

I think that is quite heavy, though… But the only alternative I can imagine is a database pregenerated table for those search purpose with an index on it. It all depends on the scale.

Except if someone else has a better solution !

Comment: One addition here : I _really_ don't understand why MySQL doesn't implement the SQLite system : the virutal table can be a joint of whatever you want, can be interrogated the way you want it… That is just how it should be. But maybe I am missing something ?